# Backbone data mapping

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, datamapper

For mapping my backbone models to what I get from the server I am using a technique described on the GroupOn Dev blog: https://engineering.groupon.com/2012/javascript/extending-backbone-js-to-map-rough-api-responses-into-beautiful-client-side-models/

However, this only maps incoming data to the model.

I would like this to go both ways, so that when I save a model, it prepares the models attributes to match the servers model.

What would be the best solution to prepare the output of the model?

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this exact same issue where my server response is completely different from what I am able to post. I discovered within the mechanics of the Backbone.sync object a way to that I could post to my server a custom JSON object in the following statement in Backbone.sync:

```
if (!options.data && model && (method == 'create' || method == 'update')) {
  params.contentType = 'application/json';
  params.data = JSON.stringify(model.toJSON());
}
```

sync evaluates if options.data does not exist then sets the params.data to the stringified model. The options.data check keyed me off. If that exists, sync will use that instead of the model. So given this, I overrode my model.save so could pass in an attributes hash that my server expects.

Here's how I overrode it:

```
save : function(key, value, options) {
    var attributes = {}, opts = {};

    //Need to use the same conditional that Backbone is using
    //in its default save so that attributes and options
    //are properly passed on to the prototype
    if (_.isObject(key) || key == null) {
        attributes = key;
        opts = value;
    } else {
        attributes = {};
        attributes[key] = value;
        opts = options;
    }

    //In order to set .data to be used by Backbone.sync
    //both opts and attributes must be defined
    if (opts && attributes) {
        opts.data = JSON.stringify(attributes);
        opts.contentType = "application/json";
    }

    //Finally, make a call to the default save now that we've
    //got all the details worked out.
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.save.call(this, attributes, opts);
}
```

So how do you use this in your case? Essentially what you'll do is create a method that reverses the mapping and returns the resulting JSON. Then you can invoke save from your view or controller as follows:

```
getReversedMapping : function() {
    ver reversedMap = {};
    ...
    return reversedMap;
},
saveToServer : function() {
    this._model.save(this.getReverseMapping, {
        success : function(model, response) {
            ...
        },
        error : function(model, response) {
            ...
        }
    })
}
```

Since your overridden save automatically copies the JSON you pass in to options.data, Backbone.sync will use it to post.

Comment: It is not a good idea to extend the `save` method. As you showed, this requires you to copy over the parameter checks. Additionally, you also ignored other checks in the original save method. Look at my answer which uses `sync` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by *Brendan Delumpa* works, but it over-complicates things.

Don't do this in your save method. You don't want to copy over these parameter checks each time (and what if they somehow change in Backbone?).

Instead, overwrite the sync method in your model like this:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...,
    sync: function (method, model, options) {
        if (method === 'create' || method === 'update') {

            // get data from model, manipulate and store in "data" variable
            // ...

            options.data = JSON.stringify(data);
            options.contentType = 'application/json';
        }

        return Backbone.Model.prototype.sync.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

That's all there is to it when you need to "prepare" the data in a server-ready format.